# Can Hydra crack a flash-based login?

Tags: passwords, brute-force, flash

Is it possible to brute force a flash login with hydra?

If not, what is a good tool to pen test a flash login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Burp Intruder](http://www.portswigger.net/burp/intruder.html). This is only in the paid version of Burp, but it's not that expensive.

You would first capture a manual login using the proxy, then use Intruder to fuzz for valid passwords.

Comment: So it's like setting up a MITM?

Comment: @Jeff - yeah, that's exactly how Burp works. You can do the MITM proxy with the free version, it's just Intruder you need a pro license for. You may be able to do this for free with Zap; I don't know if Zap supports the flash protocols (AMF, etc.) as well as Burp (which does it quite well).

Answer (score 0):

You should MITM the connection to see the actual HTTP request sent by the Flash applet (or use your browser's developer tools, they may display Flash-originated requests too).

Once you know what request is made you should be able to replicate it with Hydra.